# Why i am getting premission denied when i run backup:run from route?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run `php artisan backup:run` from route

```
Route::get('test-backup', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('backup:run');
    Log::error($exitCode); // On log i get  (1) as output
});
```

And when i call this route on url i get nothing on my directory `storage\app\backups`

To find any error i am using `clockwork` and i get this

```js
exception: ErrorException
*message: "mkdir(): Permission denied"
~string: ""
*code: 0
*file: "/srv/www/htdocs/crm/vendor/spatie/temporary-directory/src/TemporaryDirectory.php"
*line: 43
~trace: Array(66)
~previous: null
*severity: 2
backupDestination: null
```

I am trying to give premission `775` to my directory but same problem. Does anyone have know how to fix this?

Comment: `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I have tryed. Not work

Comment: @leon002 Are you able to solve it ? getting same error.